# Transit airside in London Luton?

Tags: uk, transit, airports, easyjet, ltn

Is it possible to remain completely airside in London Luton airport when changing between two Easyjet flights?  I will only have hand baggage and will already have my boarding pass printed out before going to the airport.

Answer (score 7):

**No it's not**

All international arrivals are escorted through an isolated corridor to immigration, with no transit corridor available.

Thus, all transit passengers at Luton must comply with the UK's entry (or at least landside transit) requirements.

The UK airports that do offer airside transit are Heathrow, Gatwick and Manchester.

Comment: To add insult to injury, you still need to go through security even at those places , don't you? And it's UK security so if you refuse the full body scanner as you should then they manually inspect every item of yours and take you into a side room for patdown. It's annoying but oh well. You should still opt out.